# symfony3 controller file gives a 404 error

Tags: symfony-3.1

install symfony3 on a wamp server was fine using composer

On the http://localhost:9080/SymfonyApp/web/

i get the welcome page, thats fine

Created todocontroller.php as shown below   in C:\wamp\www\symfonyApp\src\AppBundle\Controller

#

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TodoController extends Controller
   {
/**
 * @Route("/todos", name="todo_list")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    die('TODOS');
    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' =>
 realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    ]);
    } 
 }
```

#

when i go to http://localhost:9080/SymfonyApp/web/todos

I should see TODOS on the browser  but instead i get a 404 error

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with the route?

Comment: Is `todocontroller` the way you've named your php file inside `AppBundle/Controller` directory? If so, then change the name of the file to `TodoController.php` as the naming is important. Also the `TodoController.php` file name must match the class name inside this file: `class TodoController extends Controller { //... }`.